# Having two types of nodes

Tags: tikz-pgf, rounded-corners

A rather beginner question. I am using someone else's code and he has defined:

```
 \tikz@node@transformations}{}{}
\makeatother
\tikzset{nodes={draw,rounded corners},minimum height=1.5cm,minimum width=1cm}
```

I suppose this forces tikz to create only nodes of this type. How can I create normal nodes in the same picture? Each time I try to use `\node ...` I get nodes with black margins and rounded corners.

Comment: If you are not going to use that node style, just comment that line: `%\tikzset...`

Comment: I am using it many many times. But I still need to make some 'normal' nodes.

Comment: You can remove the draw using for example `\node[draw={none}]...` or you can define a new node style.

Comment: can you help me define a new draw style? This specific kind of node defined has many properties (very big preamble I am not posting here). Can you give me a minimal example of creating a new node style with properties equal to the predefined one?

Comment: See the answer below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can define a new style and use it whenever you wish. Note the style `foo` being used within the node `B`.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{tikz}
\tikzset{nodes={draw,rounded corners},minimum height=1.5cm,minimum width=1cm}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[%
    foo/.style = {red, circle, draw, inner sep=0}]

\node      (A) at (1,0) {$A$};
\node[foo] (B) at (0,0) {$0$};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]